# Websocket: binary data messages order

Tags: websocket

Lest suppose there is websocket connection between client and server. Each of them send and get binary messages. Can I be sure that according to websocket standards messages are handled in custom handlers in the same order they are send? By other words does protocol provide sequence of messages?

Comment: Which programming language you are using for Websocket Client/Server implementation?

Comment: [BinaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs)